# How to retake tutorial missions that have been declined

Tags: eve-online

I had a little bug with the tutorial and had to cancel the military 10th tutorial. How do I get the mission back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press F12 or go to the people's & Places tab. Select career agents, these should include all the agents that gave you the specific tutorials. You can right click and set the destinations to there location. Just speaking to them should be enough. There are/have been known problems with redoing tutorials, if you cannot start the tutorial at those agents try asking a game master by petitioning for it.

Comment: game master worked